Can I export UV Map as an .DXF?
I have a mesh, it's an extruded oval, I've cut some holes in it and UV unwrapped it. But what I need is a DXF of the UV map result.
We're making a table out of sheet metal and what I need is a file I can send to sheet metal folks to have cut on the laser. This is why the DXF file.
The mesh in Blender came out the way we needed it look, but it's a 3D shape and I need it flattened.
This is where the UV Mapping comes in, the UV map is perfect for what we need only I can't get an .eps/.svg to open in AutoCAD.

This is the map that I need to bring into AutoCad.
Any idea how to accomplish this?

You can use GeometryNodes to convert UV map to a "real" mesh, that might be easier to export in a supported format. May I recommend to have a look at this question : Geometry Nodes - How can I transfere UVs from on mesh to another? ? In the provided Blender file, there is already a Group Node named "UV Debug" that is doing such a thing, with probably more options that you need. But it could be a good starting point. Feel free to ask for help adapting this GN.

I maybe completely misunderstanding what you are trying to do but wouldn't a .png to .dxf convertor do the job? In Blender save the UV map as a .png then convert to .dxf using one of the free online convertors like this one:      https://sharkfoto.com/app/?tool=converter

@3fingeredfrog that would incur a precision penalty. PNG is a raster format, the round trip to pixel data and trace back to vector is lossy something your would want to avoid

@DuarteFarrajotaRamos, just thinking aloud here .... would it work better if instead of exporting from Blender as a .png the UV was exported as an .svg (100% transparent) and then converted to .dxf? I do see now that Max was asking how to do this using geometry nodes. :)

See my answer below for a possible solution. Geometry nodes might provide another interesting tool, but is probably more involved

@3fingeredfrog: my bad. I added GN in the tag list to draw attention on this possibility. Max was just mentioning the uv tag. I think Duarte answer makes more sense than GN in this case !

Open Blender preferences, go to Edit > Preferences Addons, search for UV Layout and activate the addon Export UV Layout.

Unwrap your object, and open its layout in the UV Editor.


Go to the menu UV > Export UV Layout, on the right side bar choose SVG as file format.


Open the SVG in Inkscape or any other application that can export DXF and export it to DXF.

You can then open it in any application that supports DXF.

